# No guaranteed libname when hashing data in PROC FCMP

Tags: sas, hashtable, fcmp

I'm using SAS' PROC FCMP to write some functions for recoding. These will be saved in a data set in a shared directory, so my coworkers can use them. Most of the time, the functions are just wrappers that hash a look-up table in the same directory.

Simplified example:

```
Libname OurStuff "path/to/shared/data";

DATA OurStuff.foobar;
    foo = 1;
    bar = 2;
Run;

PROC FCMP outlib = OurStuff.functions.lookup;
    Function recode_foo(foo);
        Length bar 8;
        Declare hash foobar(dataset: "OurStuff.foobar");
        rc = foobar.defineKey("foo");
        rc = foobar.defineData("bar");
        rc = foobar.defineDone();
        rc = foobar.find();
        Return(bar);
    Endsub;
Run;
```

The function works with the original libname:

```
Options cmplib = OurStuff.functions;
DATA _NULL_;
    result = recode_foo(1);
    Put result =;
Run;
```

But if somebody uses a different libname, it won't:

```
Libname OurStuff clear;
Libname WildName "path/to/shared/data";
Options cmplib = WildName.functions;

/* Results in "ERROR: Libref OURSTUFF is not assigned" */
DATA _NULL_;
    result = recode_foo(1);
Run;
```

Is there a way, other than insisting everyone uses the same libnames, to make sure these functions always work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `dataset` is a string, it can be determined at runtime.  Thus, you can pass it as a parameter to the function - either the libname, or (better) the whole dataset string.

```
PROC FCMP outlib = OurStuff.functions.lookup;
    Function recode_foo(foo,dset $);
        Length bar 8;
        Declare hash foobar(dataset: dset);
        rc = foobar.defineKey("foo");
        rc = foobar.defineData("bar");
        rc = foobar.defineDone();
        rc = foobar.find();
        Return(bar);
    Endsub;
Run;
```

Comment: Need $ after DSET in FUNCTION statement.

Comment: @Tom Good catch - one reason I prefer runnable examples (I'll make one when I have a sec)

Comment: @Joe That answer would work, but I was hoping for something more elegant than adding an extra argument to every lookup function.

Since the data set names are reliable, I think providing the library housing the data would be enough: `Function recode_foo(foo, lib $)`. This way, I can also pass the library to nested functions that also need to know where to look.